# How much SharePoint 2013 License

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, licensing

One of Our client required deploy solution in SharePoint 2013. So, we need Servers for Prod,QA,Dev. So, what would be the cost for these SharePoint Licenses. I found somewhere that it would be $7000 per server. And I'm confused about CAL. What exactly CAL is? My company having 70 Active Directory users, so I need 70 CALs?

Thanks,
Sriniavas

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint On-Premises, intranet sites are licensed using a Server/CAL (Client Access License) model. SharePoint Server 2013 is required for each running instance of the software, and CALs are required for each person or device accessing a SharePoint Server.

Just to answer your question, you need CAL licenses for users consuming the SharePoint, in additional to number of servers running SharePoint 2013.